# How to add / append html form elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have tried to append or add the form elements, i.e first name, last name, subscribe fields in the below code, on clicking the add button. I'am not clear how to append the group of form elements. Help me to find out the error.

```js
$('.popup').on('click', function() {
  let value = $('#data').val();
  if (value) {
    $('#profileCard').append('<li>' + value + '</li>');
    $('#data').val('');
  }
  if ($('#checkbox').is(':checked')) {
    $('#checked').show();
    $('#unchecked').hide();
  } else {
    $('#unchecked').show();
    $('#checked').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="row" id="data">
  <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
    <label><b>Firstname</b></label>
    <input type="" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Enter Firstname" required>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
    <label><b>Lastname</b></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" placeholder="Enter Lastname" required>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" class="mr-6" name="subscribe">
    <label><h6 ><b>Subscribe</b></h6></label>
  </div>
</form>
<div class="col-md-6 form-group">
  <button type="button" class="popup" data-trigger="focus">Add</button>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <ol id="profileCard" class="dis-none">
    <li>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Fullname: </label>
        <h5 id="fullname"></h5>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Status: </label>
        <h5 class="dis-none" id="checked">Subscribed</h5>
        <h5 class="dis-none" id="unchecked">Not Subscribed</h5>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ol>
```

Comment: `#data` is a `form` element and had no value. As such it's not clear exactly what you're attempting to do. Are you trying to clone the existing form in order to duplicate it?

Comment: Also note that your snippet is missing a jQuery reference

Comment: On clicking the add button, I want to append the form elements.

Comment: And remove them from the original `form`? You can use `append()` to do this, but note that the location you append the elements to will mean the form submission will no longer work, so in effect you're asking us to help you break your page. As such this seems to be an X/Y question where you've asked about your attempted solution instead of the problem itself. Why exactly do you feel that you need to do this?

Comment: To fetch from the original form and to display below.It works fine but I need to append those elements on clicking add button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity sake, take a look at this.

```js
$('.popup').on('click', function() {
  const fullname = $('#fname').val() + " " + $('#lname').val()
  const subscribed = $('#checkbox').is(':checked') ? 'Subscribed' : 'Not Subscribed'
  if (fullname.length) {
    $('#profileCard').append('<li><div class="form-group">Fullname: ' + fullname + '</div><div class="form-group">Status: ' + subscribed + '</div></li>');
    $('#data')[0].reset()
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="row" id="data">
  <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
    <label><b>Firstname</b></label>
    <input type="" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Enter Firstname" required>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
    <label><b>Lastname</b></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" placeholder="Enter Lastname" required>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" class="mr-6" name="subscribe">
    <label><h6 ><b>Subscribe</b></h6></label>
  </div>
</form>
<div class="col-md-6 form-group">
  <button type="button" class="popup" data-trigger="focus">Add</button>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <ol id="profileCard" class="dis-none">
    
  </ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var data = {items: [
    {id: "1", name: "abc", type: "xyz"}
]};

$('button').on('click',function(){
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var type = $('#type').val();
    var id = parseInt(data.items[data.items.length-1].id)+1;
        
    data.items.push({"id":id.toString(), "name":name,"type":type});
    console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="name"/>
<input id="type"/>
<button>add</button>
```

I guess you were looking for this!

Comment: I'am looking to append the elements i.e,(fullname, status) as 1, 2, 3 consecutively on filling the form and on clicking the  add button.

Comment: Check it out now @PonnaveenS

Comment: is this how you wanted it to be displayed?

Comment: No, I dont want to append the result but the left side input field elements.

Comment: could you just write an example below? it will be easy to understand!

Comment: on click,
1.fullname xyz
  status   xyz
2.fullname abc
  status   abc..and so on

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183739/discussion-between-ponnaveen-s-and-kedar-kodgire).